# using jquery ui: Uncaught Type Error: cannot read property 'ui' of undefined

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I am trying to use Jquery UI's draggable and droppable functions to drag the image with id 'droppable1' into a div, but I keep receiving this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined
  at jquery-ui.min.js:6
  at jquery-ui.min.js:6
  at jquery-ui.min.js:6
```

I also get this error:

```
Uncaught Reference Error: $ is not defined
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
          <!---materializecss stuff--->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <!---my stylesheet--->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
        <!--- to use jquery widgets, etc --->
        <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
          crossorigin="anonymous">

        </script>


    </head>
    <body>

     <div id = "table" class="bottom">
        <div class="col" id= "droppable1">one
            <br/>

            <img class = "clothe-pics drop" id = "clothe-pic" src = "">
        </div>
        <div class="col">two
            <br/>
            <img class = "clothe-pics" id = "pant-pic" src = "">
        </div>
        <div class="col">three
            <br/>
            <img class = "clothe-pics" id = "shoe-pic" src = "">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id = "table" class="bottom">
        <div class="col">one
            <br/>

            <img class = "clothe-pics drag" id = "draggable1"  src = "https://huckberry.imgix.net/spree/products/244895/original/wNDuXqrQOs_taylor-stitch_yosemite_shirt_0_original.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col">two
            <br/>
            <img class = "clothe-pics" id = "pant-pic" src = "">
        </div>
        <div class="col">three
            <br/>
            <img class = "clothe-pics" id = "shoe-pic" src = "">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var count;
        $(function() {
            $( ".drag" ).draggable({
                revert: true
            });
            $( ".drop" ).droppable({
                drop: function( event, ui ) {
                    /*$( this )
                        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                        .find( "p" )
                            .html( "Dropped!" );*/
                            createElements(ui.draggable, this);
                }
            });


        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm thinking that I most likely haven't scripted the jquery in the head right, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Does anyone else know how to fix this or why I'm getting the error?

Comment: You need to load jQuery itself first, then you can load the UI support library.

Comment: Ah, that solved it, thanks.